# Usage of vector + inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

What I'd like to do, is add an object to my obiektGeometryczny vector, which would be a Manipulator or kwadrat type. 
I want "przeszkoda" to be an obstacle of Manipulator or kwadrat (square in polish) type.
I've tried to use:

```
obiektGeometryczny.push_back(new Manipulator());
```

but it returns:

```
src/scena.cpp:71:36: error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
   obiektGeometryczny.push_back(new *Manipulator);
```

Below is the code:

**scena.hh**

```
#ifndef SCENA_HH
#define SCENA_HH
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <vector>
#include "manipulator.hh"
#include "kwadrat.hh"
#include "przeszkoda.h"


class scena{
        vector<przeszkoda*> obiektGeometryczny;
public:
        scena(int argc, char *argv[]);
};
#endif
```

**przeszkoda.hh**

```
#ifndef PRZESZKODA_HH
#define PRZESZKODA_HH

class przeszkoda{
    virtual void czyPrzeciecie() {;};
};
#endif
```

**manipulator.hh**

```
#ifndef MANIPULATOR_HH
#define MANIPULATOR_HH
#include "przeszkoda.hh"

class Manipulator : public przeszkoda
{
        void czyPrzeciecie();
};
#endif
```

**kwadrat.hh**

```
#ifndef KWADRAT_HH
#define KWADRAT_HH
#include "przeszkoda.hh"

class kwadrat : public przeszkoda
{
        void czyPrzeciecie();
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not minimal example - there is something more you didn't show us. Code you posted is ok - try to simplify your case, because something like this works correctly:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int x;
};

int main(void) {
    vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new A());
    return 0;
}
```